# Counting Robot Paths(python)

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know how to start on it.

Let's image a 5x5 square.

The robot starts on the upper left-hand corner and ens on the bottom right-hand corner.

We would like to have a robot travel from the start square at the upper left to the end square at the lower right.

At each square, the robot has only one of two moves:

It may go one square to the right or
It may go one square down.

Write a program to determine how many ways may this be done? In other words, how many paths are there from “start” to “end” with the moves at each step restricted as above?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

This is represented by a recursive tree traversal. You can write a single recursive method to do this, something like:

traverse_moves, taking a board state (where the robot is, in this case) and returning an integer

Compute the next moves you can make - from 0 to 2 total. If 0, return the integer `1`. If 1 or 2, create the board state for each valid move and call this method with the state you created, summing the return values of all of your calls and returning the sum you got.

e.g. for a 2x2 board, create the state where the robot is in the top left. This state has two possible moves, so it will call itself with robot bottom left and robot top right. Each of those states has one possible move and will call themself with robot bottom right. Both of these 'leaves' of the traversal tree will return 1, and these 1s will be returned and propagated and summed up the recursive to give you 2 as the correct answer.

```
Caller
  | 2
  TL calls itself with BL and TR
/ 1 \ 1
BL  TR call themselves with BR, their only valid move
| 1  | 1
BR   BR return 1s each for being leaf nodes, the 1s are returned and summed
```

EDIT: pseudocode

```
int traverseMoves(BoardState state)
{

    List<BoardState> nextMoves = possibleMovesFrom(state);
    if (nextMoves.Length == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int returnValue = 0;
    foreach (BoardState move in nextMoves)
    {
        returnValue += traverseMoves(move);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with recursive. Can someone show me the steps? I need to do the 5x5 squares.

Comment: @user2277683 Hi, check out the edit. Recursive just means, a method that calls itself.

Comment: i'm lost and confused. So first do I need create some for loops?

Comment: i know what recursive means. But the teacher didn't explain it well and no examples. And just give us this kind problem.

Comment: that looks complicated to me. Is that python language? I'm learning the intro.

Comment: @user2277683 It's pseudocode. It won't compile in any programming language, it's just meant to show structure and read well. You can see that the recursive part is that it calls itself with all the possible next board states, and they'll call themselves with all the next possible board states, and so on - and when they start reaching the end, they'll return values that get summed together and ultimately equal the number of endings found.